# how to install PyMouse on Windows

Tags: python

i am trying to use [PyMouse](https://code.google.com/p/pymouse/wiki/Documentation) plugin on windows 8.1 . 
i used this code to import library :

```
from pymouse.windows import PyMouse
```

but this error shows :

> from win32api import GetSystemMetrics 
>   ImportError: No module named
>   'win32api'

where is the problem? i am not sure that i install the library fine ! can you show how to install it on windows ?

Comment: Usually, for questions like this, you should explain how you installed it. _Especially_ if you're not sure you did it right. For example, if you downloaded PyMouse-0.4.tar.gz from the website, unpacked it by double-clicking in Explorer, then opened a `cmd` window, `cd`'d to the directory, and did `pip install .`, tell us that. In this case, it was simple enough to figure out without that information, but often it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `win32api` module is part of [`PyWin32`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32), so you need to install that.

Meanwhile, you should be installing things with `pip` whenever possible. Some packages aren't `pip`-installable, or have incorrect requirements specs, but *most* packages, if you try to `pip` install them, will either automatically fetch their dependencies or complain that they're missing.

---

Also it looks like [PyMouse's documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pymouse/wiki/Documentation) is wrong, because it claims to only require `ctypes` (which comes with Python 2.6+), not `PyWin32`, on Windows. You may want to [file a documentation bug with them](https://code.google.com/p/pymouse/issues/).

However, it looks like the `PyMouse` you were using was abandoned at version 0.4 about 6 years ago. It was then [picked up by someone else](https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse), but, as the README says, it was later merged into [`PyUserInput`](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput). So, you probably want to use that instead.

Note that `PyUserInput` correctly mentions the other dependencies in its README. It also checks them in its [`setup.py`](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput/blob/master/setup.py) file. So hopefully, all you have to do is:

```
pip install PyUserInput
```

… and it will either pull in PyWin32 and pyHook, or complain that you have to go get them manually.